# Adding breakpoint to custom theme in Material UI Next (reactjs)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm creating a custom theme with mui as follows:

```
export default createMuiTheme({
  breakpoints: {
    keys: [
      "xxs",
      "xs",
      "sm",
      "md",
      "lg",
      "xl",
    ],
    values: {
      xxs: 0,
      xs: 414, // iPhone X and below in portrait mode
      sm: 600,
      md: 960,
      lg: 1280,
      xl: 1920,
    },
  },
})
```

But when I try to use it in a class declaration like so:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    [theme.breakpoints.down('xxs')]: {
      textAlign: "center",
      padding: theme.spacing.unit * 2,
    },
  },
})
```

I get the following CSS:

```
@media (max-width:NaNpx) {
  .root-3 {
    padding: 16px;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

Is there a special way to add a custom breakpoint vs. just modifying existing ones?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Currently it is only possible to customize the *values* of the predefined breakpoints. Here is an example:

```js
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  breakpoints: {
    values: {
      xs: 0,
      sm: 450,
      md: 600,
      lg: 900,
      xl: 1200
    }
  }
});
```

[image: Edit Material-UI Custom breakpoints]

The breakpoint names cannot be configured. There is a comment in  [createBreakpoints.js](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v1-beta/src/styles/createBreakpoints.js) explaining this:

```js
// Sorted ASC by size. That's important.
// It can't be configured as it's used statically for propTypes.
export const keys = ['xs', 'sm', 'md', 'lg', 'xl'];
```

---

**UPDATE (September 2018):**

This feature has been requested and is currently under discussion.  See [material-ui/issues/11649](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/11649)

Comment: As of 09/2020 it's still not working. The issue is active though.

Comment: Breakpoints can be customly edited now: mui.com/customization/breakpoints/#custom-breakpoints

Answer (score 1):

In case you prefer not to change the default values,
You can use a quick workaround,
use the theme breakpoints field to change the breakpoint value where needed.

For example:

xxl breakpoint

```
 [theme.breakpoints.up(theme.breakpoints.values.xl + CUSTOM_BREAKPOINT_DIFFERENCE)]: {
  padding: "0 3.5rem",
},
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated [here](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/breakpoints/#custom-breakpoints) it's now possible :

```js
// MUI theme

const theme = createTheme({
    breakpoints: {
        values: {
            xxs: 0,
            xs: 300,
            sm: 600,
            md: 900,
            lg: 1200,
            xl: 1500,
            xxl: 1800
        }
    }
});

// Typescript module augmentation

import '@mui/material';

declare module '@mui/material/styles' {
    interface BreakpointOverrides {
        xxs: true;
        xs: true;
        sm: true;
        md: true;
        lg: true;
        xl: true;
        xxl: true;
    }
}
```