# Material UI custom breaking point not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, themes, media-queries

I was using the default breakingpoint provided by Material UI  for my media queries , then added one more breaking point (mobile : 400)  , all the other breaking points works fine except when i reach to the width of 400px the changes doesnt take effect at that point , am i doing anything wrong here?

```
const theme = createTheme({
 breakpoints: {
      values: {
        xs: 0,
        mobile: 400,
        sm: 600,
        md: 900,
        lg: 1200,
        xl: 1536,
      },
    },
```

at below when the screen reachs 600px width MQsm value turns to 'true'  , but when i reach the width of 400px  MQmb doesnt change.

```
const Navbar = (props) => {
  const cartQuantity = useSelector((state) => state.cart.totalQuantity);
  const classes = useStyles();
  const theme = useTheme();
  const MQsm = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down("sm")); //600px
  const MQmb = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down("mobile")); //360px
  console.log(MQsm);
  console.log(MQmb);
```

Comment: You can override values to the built-in break points, but currently, you cannot add custom breakpoint keys (but you're right ... you should be able to do that):
See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49739635/adding-breakpoint-to-custom-theme-in-material-ui-next-reactjs)

Comment: But in the docs  it mentions i can add as many customs break points as i want ,  im not sure back then how was it coz this question was three years ago

Comment: Are you using MUI Version 5?

Comment: yeah.. i can provide you with the entire code.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-platform-38hnpb